# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader findLibrary returned null

Tags: android-ndk

I understand this is asked many times, but I have done thorough research before posting my query.

I have updated Android Studio to latest version as of March 2nd 2015, version 1.1.0. I think still grade does not package .so files on its own.

I have written NewNDK.c in /jni folder. Ran the ndk-build script and .so files were created in /libs. As per suggestion in one of the posts, I modified libs to lib.

Even then, I am getting java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader findLibrary returned null error.

The posts does not say about which files to modify. I am new to Android, request your help.

I have narrowed down the problem to: 1. Gradle is not packaging 2. Gradle scripts should be modified.

The build.gradle (Module: app) is as below:

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.raghu.newndk"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 17
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
}
```

The build.gradle (project) is as below:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Please let me know what is missing.

Thank You!

Answer (score 3):

> As per suggestion in one of the posts, I modified libs to lib.

It doesn't really make sense to do that. `lib` is the folder where your .so files will go inside the APK, but this step will be handled directly by the packaging tools if your project is correctly organized.

Inside an Android Studio project, you should put the *.so files* inside `jniLibs/<ABI>` where `<ABI>` is the target architecture of each .so file (*armeabi*, *x86*... the same way that they are generated from the NDK inside *libs*).

So you can either rename your `libs` folder to `jniLibs`, or configure your build so your .so files from `libs` will be directly integrated:

```
android {
    ...
    sourceSets.main {
        jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Open the project properties > go to Andriod options > select Advance tab > just uncheck "armeabi","armeabi-v7a","arm64-v8a" and save the project.

The Error will be removed.